# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}/n^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

One problem saying:

Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/(x^{2}+n^{2})$ uniform convergence?

So I solved it using Weierstrass M test since $\mathbb R $ is complete and $g_k\leq 1/k^2$ and the series consisting of $1/k^2$ is convergent by P-series test.

But what I want to know is the following problem:

Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}/n^{2}$ uniformly convergent on $x\in [0,1]$?

To solve it, I tried to use Cauchy Criterion.

So, I tried to find, for given $\epsilon$, certain $N$ for that condition.

For $k\geq N$

$\|g_{k}(x)+\cdots+g_{k+p}(x)\|=\|\frac{x^{k}}{k^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{x^{k+p}}{(k+p)^{2}}\|\leq\|\frac{1}{k^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k^{2}}\|=\frac{p}{k^{2}}.$

How can I find such $N$?

Comment: No, it cannot be convergent, as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n^2$ has convergence radius $1$

Comment: Your second series is convergent in $[-1,1]$ by the $M$-test.

Comment: Ah! It's all my fault. problem gives me  "Only $x\in[0,1]$" condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n \geq 1$,
then
$$
x^{n}/n^{2} \leq 1/n^{2}
$$
for all $x \in [0,1]$;
by comparison test the uniform convergence follows.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I fixed it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Then what value should I take as $N$? If I choose $N=1/\sqrt \epsilon$ then for $n\geq N$, $||g_k (x)+\cdots +g_{k+p} (x)||\leq||1/n^2 +\cdots +1/n^2 ||=p/\epsilon. $

Comment: @Darae-Uri I was suggesting a quicker and to me more elegant way to see the uniform convergence; Cauchy's stuff can make things messy. :)

Comment: Ah! I see. Thank you for your comment. :D

Comment: @Darae-Uri Sorry for the careless version of my previous answer.